# OroCommerce 4.2: Export Price List. Error: Orphans were found and redelivered. consumerIds:

Tags: orocommerce

I have a problem, it does not export the price lists and it reports the following error by mail.

Orphans were found and redelivered. consumerIds: "64939fec392e05.70085169, 6493a055b7ec90.88552179, 6493a05d9431a4.72716877"

extension: | Oro\Component\MessageQueue\Consumption\Dbal\Extension\RedeliverOrphanMessagesDbalExtension

I verified configurations on the server, it runs on Centos 7, Php7.4, it has resources available on the server, it exports the products well but not the price lists. The Job task remains at 50%.

Comment: This is not an issue, but expected behavior that happens after force kill of the consumer